# Session is null in HttpHandler but not in MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I have security in my MVC application set up with an authorize attribute...

```
public class UserLoggedInAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserId"] == null)
            {
                var values = new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" };
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(values));
            }
        }

    }
```

Then I also have a .ashx HttpHandler which is called by jQuery upload control....

```
public class UploadFile : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
    {

...

private bool EnsureSecureTransaction(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Session["UserId"] == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

            return true;
        }

}
```

When EnsureSecureTransaction() gets called the session is coming back null. But session that is read in my MVC action its not. I notice that I'm taking session from the filterContext though.

I have tried to change all the code to try and reference HttpContext.Current.Session like this

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Logon(AdminModel model)
        {

            if (model.UserName == "x" && model.Password == "x")
            {
                HttpContext.Session["UserId"] = "true";

                return RedirectToAction("CreateBlog", "Blog");

            }


            return View;
        }


        private bool EnsureSecureTransaction(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Session["UserId"] == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

But basically when I hit the EnsureSecureTransaction() block its still saying my Session["UserId"] is null and therefor not autehenticating the call to the .ashx file correctly.

Anyone know why this is? Whats the actual difference between AuthorizationContext and HttpContext with regards to the session they carry and how do I get round this problem?

Comment: Have you checked that something strange isn't going on with your server. Get MVC and jQuery to return the SessionId. I could be that jQuery is getting a different server session.

Comment: How are you registering your HTTP handler?  You might be executing it too soon in the HTTP pipeline.